# Why am I getting no rows as a result of the subquery that has records when run alone

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to fetch records to outer query finding records found in the subquery.

```
select * from booker.d_air_shipments_na where 
(fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id) in 
(select fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id
from booker.d_air_shipments_na 
where datediff(day, customer_order_date,ext_dea_day)<=1 
and customer_order_date>=current_Date -7)--
and substring(zone,1,1) like 'K'
and substring(zone,9,1) like 'K');

select fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id, substring(zone,1,1), substring(zone,9,1) from booker.d_air_shipments_na limit 100;
```

When I run the lower query I do get an output like

```
Column     Substring   Substring
XYZABC     K           K
```

I want all the records with above condition in the outer query of the code but am not able to

The overall result should look like this for the entire query for all fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id found in subquery. The picture attached is for all the records as a result of smaller query at the bottom. Since there are records with both K in 2nd and 3rd column, I am trying to fetch only those records for outer query

Fulfillment_shipment_id||package_id   column1   column2 column3

Comment: Edit your question and explain what the code is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results can really help.

Answer (score 0):

how is that different from

```
select * 
from booker.d_air_shipments_na
where datediff(day, customer_order_date,ext_dea_day)<=1 
and customer_order_date>=current_date-7
and substring(zone,1,1) = 'K'
and substring(zone,9,1) = 'K';
```

I don't think you need a subquery here since you're trying to filter the same table there

as for why you're getting data in the lower query and not getting data in the upper query, seems like you don't have records with this condition:

```
where datediff(day, customer_order_date,ext_dea_day)<=1 
and customer_order_date>=current_Date -7
```

that also have "K" zone substrings